# NLog using current date for folder and startup time for filename

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm running with NLog 4.6.6, and very new at it.
I'm trying to configure the logging path and log files such that the the folder containing the log files uses the current date, and the log file is formatted with the startup time.

I've gotten to successfully work somewhat, but it's creating a new file each second. which is of course, not idea.

The only additional caveat is that if the day rolls over while logging, i need a new folder and file created.

Original configuration that creates a file every second:

```
<target name="logfile"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="C:\AppLogs\Logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}\${date:format=HH.mm.ss}.log"
        layout="[${longdate}]  ${level:uppercase=false} Assembly: ${processname:fullName=false} Class.Method: ${callsite:includeNamespace=false}: ${callsite-linenumber}\n${message}" />
```

Here's what i tried for cached format:

```
<target name="logfile"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${cached:cached=true:inner=C:\Applogs\Logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}\${date:format=HH.mm.ss}}.log"
        layout="${counter}${longdate}  ${level:uppercase=true} Assembly: ${processname:fullName=false} Class.Method: ${callsite:includeNamespace=false} Line: ${callsite-linenumber} Message: ${message}" />
```

Updating to use cached has prevented any files from being written, so i'm guessing i have a formatting error somewhere.
Any suggestions for how to correct this?

Comment: If needing to troubleshoot NLog Logging Configuration, then one can use `throwConfigExceptions="true"` or enable the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging). See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: But I'm guessing that you suddenly need to escape back-slashes, and colons. As the `FileName`-Layout has special handling to accept raw windows-file-paths. This would probably also work: `fileName="C:\AppLogs\Logs\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd:cached=true}\${date:format=HH.mm.ss:cached=true}.log"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider using [${processinfo:StartTime}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ProcessInfo-Layout-Renderer) like this:

```xml
<target name="logfile"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="C:\AppLogs\Logs\${processinfo:StartTime:format=yyyy-MM-dd:cached=true}\${processinfo:StartTime:format=HH.mm.ss:cached=true}.log"
        layout="[${longdate}]  ${level:uppercase=false} Assembly: ${processname:fullName=false} Class.Method: ${callsite:includeNamespace=false}: ${callsite-linenumber}\n${message}" />
```

Then it might be more obvious for the next developers to understand the naming-convention.

Comment: This does the trick. I'd say the only part that is missing is the day rollover. It's not a dealbreaker, IMO, but certainly something I'd love to get working if possible

Comment: @Jason Maybe replace `${processinfo:StartTime:format=yyyy-MM-dd:cached=true}` with `${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}`. Then NLog will create a folder for each day, but the FileName will be unchanged (original process-start-time).

Comment: @Jason Alternative replace `${processinfo:StartTime:format=HH.mm.ss:cached=true}.log` with `${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}_${processinfo:StartTime:format=HH.mm.ss:cached=true}.log`. Then NLog will create a startup-folder and "roll" to new files inside the startup-folder.